# create div, h3 using for loop and insert array variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a web application in which I have to fill user friend list using JavaScript. I used the following code to perform that, but I don't get any name inside it and only div are created I need to create heading also. How to add heading using javascript and fill value in it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var name = ["Amar", "rahul", "vinay"];
    var hobby=["aaa","bbb","ccc"];
    var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for(var i=0; i <name.length; i++){
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var newheading = document.createElement("h2");
        newDiv.id='r'+i;
        newDiv.id='h'+i;
        newDiv.innerHTML = name[i];
        newDiv.className = 'ansbox';
        toAdd.appendChild(newDiv);
    }
    document.getElementById('sel').appendChild(toAdd);
```

Comment: Show your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var name = ["Amar", "rahul", "vinay"];
  var hobby=["aaa","bbb","ccc"];
  var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for(var i=0; i <name.length; i++){
     var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
     var newheading = document.createElement("h2");
     newheading.innerText = hobby[i];
     newDiv.id='r'+i;
     newDiv.id='h'+i;
     newDiv.innerHTML = name[i];
     newDiv.className = 'ansbox';
     toAdd.appendChild(newheading);
     toAdd.appendChild(newDiv);
 }
```

document.getElementById('sel').appendChild(toAdd)
});

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/auecLdu9/)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: it's help me to solve this problem, you have done a mistake newheading.innerText = hobby[i]; is wrong newheading.innerHTML = hobby[i]; is right Now it's work

Answer (score 0):

Hope This Will Help. Add the heading element inside division

```
 newDiv.appendChild(newheading);
```

Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jq59snz9/)

Comment: I need one more help If I want to show that heading inside new created div then how I write that code
Currenty it looks like---<div id="sel"> <h2>aaa</h2> <div id=r0>amar</div></div>

how can I show it like--<div id="sel">  <div id=r0>amar <h2>aaa</h2></div></div>

Comment: <div id="sel"><div id="h0" class="ansbox">Amar<h2>Amar</h2></div><div id="h1" class="ansbox">rahul<h2>rahul</h2></div><div id="h2" class="ansbox">vinay<h2>vinay</h2></div></div>  . This is the format you looking for?? @yogi

Answer (score 0):

If you want the div to appear in that order just reverse the order in which you write appendChild like adding "toAdd.appendChild(newDiv);" first and then adding "toAdd.appendChild(newheading);" later.